Why is being gay haram?
I understand and know that being with the same sex is haram but why exactly? This is coming from someone who is straight. I’m just curious because I know Allah wants us to choose Islam because it’s logical, not because we’re told to, therefore I am wondering and hoping to get an answer. What in the Quran hints at homosexuality being haram? Is it haram for someone to question their sexuality. Is it ok for someone to feel like they’re attracted to the same sex as long as they don’t act on it or will you go to hell for thinking you like the same sex? I would really love to get some answers to my question.

According to Quran:

وَ لُوطًا إِذْ قَالَ لِقَوْمِهِ إِنَّكُمْ لَتَأْتُونَ الْفَاحِشَةَ مَا سَبَقَكُمْ بِهَا مِنْ أَحَدٍ مِنَ الْعَالَمِينَ، أَئِنَّكُمْ لَتَأْتُونَ الرِّجَالَ وَ تَقْطَعُونَ السَّبِيلَ ... [العنکبوت، ۲۸]
And [mention] Lot, when he said to his people, Ye do commit lewdness, such as no people in Creation (ever) committed before you. Indeed, you approach men and obstruct the road? ...

so that a main reason counted is perhaps obstructing the road ... In another verse Allah seemingly explains this a little bit by stating:

إِنَّكُمْ لَتَأْتُونَ الرِّجَالَ شَهْوَةً مِنْ دُونِ النِّسَاءِ بَلْ أَنْتُمْ قَوْمٌ مُسْرِفُونَ [الأعراف، ۸۱]
Indeed, you approach men with desire, instead of women. Rather, you are indeed a people transgressing beyond bounds.

which means leaving women in preference of men is a transgressing beyond bounds. Transgressing beyond bounds usually apply to over usage of goods, but also sometimes to misusage of goods. For example in a Hadeeth, eating an animal which is Haram to eat for human kind, is coined the name transgressing beyond bounds, as we have wasted the life of an animal where we have not had the permission to kill it for eating. Allah has placed the sexual desire for the production of new generations, not only between men and women of human kind, but also between the opposite genders of other species (not talking about the exceptions). This avoiding reproduction and using sex merely for sexual satisfaction (not to mean that every sexual relation should be a try for reproductioni, has having sexual relation between normal men and women has also other functions in family), will be a misuse, as masturbation is Haram the same way, being called self-marriage. These are called cutting or obstructing the road (تَقْطَعُونَ السَّبِيلَ). This is not however the only reason for it being a misuse, as the anal sex even between common spouse is also hardly considered Halal, strongly discouraged.
PS. That you said "Allah wants us to choose Islam because it’s logical, not because we’re told to, therefore I am wondering and hoping to get an answer" seems not to be really correct. First, choosing Islam is not meant to be logical, but by intellect (عقل) and heart (قُلُوبٌ يَعْقِلُونَ بِهَا), logic being only one possible activator for intellect, and more than that, to logically get rid of the logical/experimental obstacles in believing what is otherwise clearly obvious (قَالَتْ رُسُلُهُمْ أَفِي اللَّهِ شَكٌّ فَاطِرِ السَّمَاوَاتِ وَ الْأَرْضِ؟) for those who have a sound heart (قَلْبٍ سَلِيمٍ). Second, choosing Islam as the right religion on our own is one thing, and trying to know the reasons behind any and every rule in Islam is another thing, in the former case every one should decide by him/herself, while for the latter everyone should submit to the religion he/she has accepted as the true religion from the God. Submitting means accepting without caring about the reasons, while anyway trying to knowing the reasons is encouraged, if possible.
